# Make a GameObject indestructible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making a shooting game using Raycasts in Unity. I have a gameObject which is a cube (The ground for my game). That cube can be destroyed by using `Destroy()` method. How do I make it indestructible so that it doesn't get destroyed even after using the `Destroy()` method?

This my FPS gun script so far:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 20f;
    public float range = 150f;
    //public GameObject ground;
    public Camera fpsCamera;
    void Start()
    {
        //DontDestroyOnLoad(ground);
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    void Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hitObject;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCamera.transform.position, fpsCamera.transform.forward, out hitObject, range) && hitObject.transform.name != "Ground") {
            Destroy(hitObject.transform.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This can be done by not using the `Destroy()` method

Comment: You can also use DontDestroyOnLoad to mark the object not to be destroyed on loading a new scene. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

Comment: I am making a shooting game using Raycasts, So the objects collided with the Raycast are Destroyed.

Comment: Can you add the part of the code that destroy objects ?

Comment: Added the script to the question

Comment: Your code should actually be working because of `&& hitObject.transform.name != "Ground"` Make sure to check the ground gameobject name. You can use `Debug.Log(hitObject.transform.name);` before calling `Destroy();` to check the name of the destroyed object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to sort which objects are destroyed somehow. The most simple way is of course to not call the Destroy method on that object in the first place.

However since you explain in the comments you wish to shoot and destroy some objects but not all. I would in your case make a script which either checks the tag, layer or calls a method in a script on each object.

For example, you try something similar to this:

```
ObjectProperties : MonoBehaviour{
    public boolean CanBeDestroyed = true;
}
```

Add that script to the objects you shoot at.

And then when your raycast hits an object, use `GetComponent` on the object shot to try get `ObjectProperties` from that object. If the object hit has a `ObjectProperties` that isn't null, and that `ObjectProperties` has `CanBeDestroyed` set to be true. Then you may destroy the object.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way of achieving this, is using tags. Create a tag by highlighting the object. In the Inspector open the tags tab. Then create a tag and assign it to your object. The last thing you need to do is to check in code which tag the object you hit has.

`if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCamera.transform.position, fpsCamera.transform.forward, out hitObject, range) && hitObject.transform.name != "Ground") {
            switch (hitObject.tag)
            {
                case "immortal": //Nothing happens
                   break;
                case "veryweak": //Objects with this tag get destroyed
                   Destroy(hitObject.transform.gameObject);
                   break;
                default: //Objects that do not have a tag and do not match any of the above get destroyed
                   Destroy(hitObject.transform.gameObject);
                   break;
             }
        }`

Hope that helps.